# MapReduce: map objects from another bucket against a list of keys (without link walking)?

Tags: java, scala, mapreduce, riak

**Edit:** Looks like the concept is known as "forwarding and collecting". Going to see how this works in the Riak-Java client.

Right now performing a simple MapReduce in Riak that returns a list of keys of `User` objects. To keep things simple, I want to simply map the values of a `User` to the keys and return a list of users. Here's what I've got so far in Scala (using Java client) and FYI the key is composite and looks like `clientId-userId`:

```
val map = new JSSourceFunction("""
      function(riakObject){ 
            var rolek = riakObject.key;   
            return [rolek];
          }
    """)
        val reduce = new JSSourceFunction("""
      function(value){ 
            var returnValue=[], splitarr=[];  
            for(i=0;i<value.length;i++){ 
              splitarr=String(value[i]).split("-"); 
              returnValue = returnValue.concat([splitarr[1]]);  
            } 
            return returnValue; 
          }
    """)
    DB.client.mapReduce("rolesOfClientAdmins")
    .addKeyFilter(new TokenizeFilter("-", 1))
    .addKeyFilter(new MatchFilter(clientId))
    .addMapPhase(map)
    .addReducePhase(reduce)
    .execute().getResult(classOf[String])
```

Do I add another Map phase after the Reduce phase? Do I need to somehow change buckets? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You wouldn't add a map after the reduce - you run a reduce after you've gathered all your data with one or more map phases

Comment: Ah understood. And from Google research, it looks like I also need to return the bucket during the map phase, like `return [[value.bucket, value.key]]`

Comment: If you want to add another map phase, then you need to return the bucket & key together in that way. I'm not exactly sure what your question is in order to write a full answer :)

Comment: I can see where I wasn't clear. Basically, the code above is already returning a list of keys (userIDs) from `rolesOfClientAdmins` bucket. Instead, I want to return full user objects themselves stored in `users` bucket. Similar to a SQL join, but just not sure how it works in the Java client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with the `rolesOfClientAdmins` bucket as the input and split the key to get the `User` object's ID. Then pass the bucket name "users" and the user ID into the next map phase.

```
val mapRolesBucket = new JSSourceFunction("""
      function(value){
            var splitarr=value.key.split('-'); 
            return [[ 'users', splitarr[1] ]];
          }
    """)
val mapUsersBucket = new JSSourceFunction("""
      function(value){
            var obj = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0];
            return [ obj ];
          }
    """)
    DB.client.mapReduce("rolesOfClientAdmins")
    .addKeyFilter(new TokenizeFilter("-", 1))
    .addKeyFilter(new MatchFilter(clientId))
    .addMapPhase(mapRolesBucket)
    .addMapPhase(mapUsersBucket)
    .execute().getResult(classOf[String])
```

Comment: Seems simple, except does this reference the `users` bucket to pull the values? Do I need to add a link somewhere? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Np. I'm not actually familiar with the client you're using - but in this code the bucket is called `rolesOfClientAdmins`. If your bucket is called `users`, change the code there. I'll update the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Ah I see. Basically since a user can have multiple admin relationships, we're working with 2 different buckets. So we're getting the list of keys from `rolesOfClientAdmins` but the user objects themselves would come from `users` bucket. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Aha! I'm with you now. We'll get this answer sorted, and then it might be worth updating your question a bit ;)

Comment: Appreciated. And yes, I can assure the question will be updated LOL.

Comment: PhaseError: `ReferenceError: i is not defined`. Was the `mapRoles` meant to be inside a loop?

Comment: Ah sorry about that- I couldn't test that bit and didn't check it carefully enough. The code is splitting your composite key of `clientId-userId`. Answer has been updated.

Comment: WOW this is still really simple. Accepting this, and I'll say it again: thank you!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26411/discussion-between-mafro-and-delongey)